# create json file on server with php

Tags: php, cors, nuxt.js

I want to save a Json file to the server via Nuxt (localhost:3000).
Unfortunately I still get the CORS error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The same-source rule prohibits reading the external resource on http://localhost:8000/fetch.php. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is missing).

The php Script is:

```
<?php

// For development only (CORS issues)
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); // For development only
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT'); // For development only
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept, x-requested-with"); // For development only
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');


$post_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post_body_decoded = json_decode($post_body, true);
$response_data = [
    'success' => true,
    'what_we_posted' => $post_body_decoded,
];

file_put_contents('myfile.json', json_encode($response_data))

exit();
```

in .vue

```
    const { data: responseData } = await useFetch('http://localhost:8000/fetch.php', {
        method: 'post',
        body: { 
          name: formData.value.name,
          email: formData.value.email,
          message: formData.value.message, 
        }
    })
```

`echo json_encode($response_data);` instead of
 `file_put_contents('myfile.json', json_encode($response_data))`
works fine.
I am working on Ubuntu 22.04.

Thanks!
Gordon

Comment: Is the comment necessary on every line? This looks like the code example is over-reacting. Can you verify the response headers with [Curl](https://curl.se) [from the command-line](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5vZWHP-RqU)? E.g. sending the [pre-flight request with OPTIONS method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) and see if your HTTP application server is actually passing along the request to PHP and the response from PHP?

Comment: `http://localhost:8000/fetch.php` is not `localhost:3000` can you check what you are really doing

Comment: _"`echo json_encode($response_data);` instead of `file_put_contents('myfile.json', json_encode($response_data))` works fine."_ - that sounds as if the latter might be causing some sort of error (which might then in turn prevent the correct CORS headers from being sent to the client), have you checked the error log?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. In fact the message came because ```file_put_contents``` doesn't work(?)
If I try ```$myfile = fopen('myfile.json','w+');  
$txt = json_encode($response_data);  
fwrite($myfile, $txt);  
fclose($myfile);    ``` it works.